# 'float' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python-2.7, floating-point-precision

This is supposed to find `pi` to the `k`th digit, however my float seems to be off? Any suggestions?

```
for k in range (0,1000):
    pi[k] = (16**(-1*k)) *((4/(8*k +1)) - (2/(8*k +4)) - (1/(8*k +5)) - (1/(8*k +6)))
print pi[2]
```

Comment: What language would this be ? Please tag appropriately.

Comment: Also, if this is C or C++ please include the architecture of the machine this is running on.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your requirement but it can be done with the help of floating type array

```
import array
arr1=array.array('f')
arr1.append(2.9)
arr1.append(30.4584)
print arr1
```

You can append any number element in it and i have tested it for 921600 element.
For more information regarding array please visit the below linkhttps://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html